# How are NSManagedObjects managed in memory

Tags: core-data, nsmanagedobject

How are NSManagedObjects managed in memory if multiple VCs fetch data from the database using different fetch limitations.

E.g. One VC fetches based on names and only wants to present names in a tableview thus only holds the name data from the fetched NSManagedObjects in memory, not the rest of the object.

This allows selected data to be held in memory, How is the memory used when more than one VC is holding onto the same data at once? Will there be copies of this data for each reference or are the NSManagedObjects' backing data the single entry in Core-Data?

If so, does Core-Data use virtual memory mapping for on demand reading of these single instances or is the actual data loaded into memory as copies?

Comment: "One VC fetches based on names and only wants to present names in a tableview thus only holds the name data from the fetched NSManagedObjects in memory, not the rest of the object." Could you post some example code? It's a little hard to be sure what you're describing.

Answer (score 1):

There won't be any copies of the objects. As long as you are using the same store/context there will only be one copy(a feature called uniquing). There is also something called as faulting which helps in reducing the memory footprint in core-data. 
Faults mean instances of a managed object with un-initialized iVars.Fault can be triggerd (i.e ivars initialized) in many ways. (Expecially useful in relationships). Check out here for more: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdFaultingUniquing.html

But according to my understanding, you can't just keep one property(like name data) of managed objects in memory. The whole of the object will be in memory.